# DataTable retrieve json from dataSrc unknown parameter

Tags: html, ajax, datatables

I have a problem when population results from my ajax to datatables, i already verified that my ajax function works and return results

[image: Result from the console]

Here is my javascript code:

```
function getBookingRecords() {
tblDirectLoanReceipt = $('#tbBooking').DataTable();
tblDirectLoanReceipt.destroy();
tblDirectLoanReceipt = $('#tbBooking').DataTable({
    autoWidth: true,
    initComplete: function () {
    },
    processing: true,
    serverSide:true,
    ajax: {
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: '/Booking/RetrieveBookingRecords',
        dataSrc: function (json) {
            console.log(json);
            return json;
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'dsm_description' },
            { data: 'code' }
        ]
    }
});
```

}

and my html code:

```
@section Scripts
{
    @Helper.LoadCustomJS("ViewsJS/Booking/JS_Booking.js", Url)
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="tbBooking">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>dsm_description</th>
                        <th>code</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i possibly fix this issue? What am i missing? thanks for any help in advance :)

update:

Error result

[image]

Comment: Rather than have a function in your `dataSrc` replace it with an empty string. `Note that if your Ajax source simply returns an array of data to display, rather than an object, set this parameter to be an empty string.` https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make sure your returned json data from ajax be formated like the following

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      ...   
      "dsm_description": "Sample description 1",
      "code": "Sample code 1",
      ...
    },
    {
      ...   
      "dsm_description": "Sample description 2",
      "code": "Sample code 2",
      ...
    }]
}
```

To format returned json data, you could try to use library JSON.NET

```
var listData = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();  
....
var result = new {Data = listData};
return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), "application/json");
```

Comment: how? I'm returning data as List<Dictionary<string,object>>() @trung duong

Comment: Which library are you using to serialize List to Json, or you just return data using a JsonResult in your controller?

Comment: im just using the Json function in the controller

Comment: I think you could try to wrap it in a dynamic object like var result = new { Data = <your list> }; then return it by Json(result) (I've not tried it yet). I've updated my answer to use Json.net library (it's completely free), please check it

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
function getBookingRecords() {
  tblDirectLoanReceipt = $('#tbBooking').DataTable();
  tblDirectLoanReceipt.destroy();
  tblDirectLoanReceipt = $('#tbBooking').DataTable({
    autoWidth: true,
    initComplete: function() {},
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      type: 'post',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      url: '/Booking/RetrieveBookingRecords',
      dataSrc: "",
      columns: [{
        data: 'dsm_description'
      }, {
        data: 'code'
      }]
    }
  });
```

As per my [comment](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc).

> Note that if your Ajax source simply returns an array of data to
>   display, rather than an object, set this parameter to be an empty
>   string.

Hope that helps.